# Visual Studio 2019 imports TS files using relative paths instead of using 'paths' alias from tsconfig file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I recently switched to using TS paths which allows me to write

```
import { DateService } from "@services/date.service";
```

Instead of

```
import { DateService } from "../../../../services/date.service";
```

VS can understand these paths, as can webpack. However when, using Visual Studio 2019, I create an import via the actions menu, it always adds new imports using relative paths as opposed to using the TypeScript path aliases.

How do I make VS create new import references using the path aliases?

TS config :

```
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "paths": {
            "@services/*": [ "./src/app/services/*" ],
            "@interfaces/*": [ "./src/app/interfaces/*" ],
            "@directives/*": [ "./src/app/directives/*" ],
            "@enums/*": [ "./src/app/enum/*" ]
        },
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [ "node" ]
    },
    "include": [ "./src/**/*.ts" ],
    "files": [
        "./src/app/bootstrap.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of Typescript you are using?

Comment: @Eldar I am using 3.9.6 inside my package.json, but there is a possibility VS is using an older version. Would upgrading TS within VS help?

Comment: Can you try the solution described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/520769/typescript-imports-with-relative-path.html)